# Unable to watch images using freemarker

Tags: image, apache-spark, freemarker

I’ve been trying to add an image to the web page but for the moment It’s been impossible to visualize it.

I added the following to the .ftl file:

```
<img  src="../images/poweredby_big_ffffff.png"  alt="My image">`
```

the path of images folder is the following:

```
Desktop\proyect\src\main\resources\images
```

I’m using freemarker 2.3.19 and apache spark

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with FreeMarker actually. The image is loaded
by your browser, not by FreeMarker. The image URL is resolved by the
browser relatively to the URL where the FreeMarker-generated page
appears. That final URL then must point to the visitable URL of the
image.

P.s.: Don't use old FreeMarker versions like 2.3.19.